# Tcl_AsyncDelete Error. Unable to terminate Tk

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, rospy

I am using Tkinter in a ROS node to create a GUI and publish the scale values to another ROS Node. I have accomplished this. The problem comes when I try to close this GUI and rerun the node. The log message that I get is as follows:

```
Exception RuntimeError: 'main thread is not in main loop' in <bound method DoubleVar.__del__ of <Tkinter.DoubleVar instance at 0x7f19ea0c3ab8>> ignored
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
Aborted (core dumped)
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073762/tcl-asyncdelete-error-multithreading-python), I think I will have to terminate Tk from its own thread. But I do not know how to do this. My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float64MultiArray
from Tkinter import *  
from calibration_camera_lidar.msg import Euler_val
import tkMessageBox

class slider():

    def __init__(self):
            rospy.loginfo("init") 
            rospy.init_node('slider', anonymous=True, disable_signals=True)    
            self.spub = rospy.Publisher('Slider_values', Euler_val, queue_size=10)
            self.final_ev = Euler_val()                    
            self.listener()                             

    def listener(self):

            rospy.Subscriber("Euler_values", Float64MultiArray, self.callback)
            rospy.spin()

    def callback(self, data):  

                self.eulerval = list(data.data)
                self.final_ev.Euler_angles = [self.eulerval[0], self.eulerval[1], self.eulerval[2]]
                self.spub.publish(self.final_ev)
                rospy.loginfo(self.final_ev)               
                self.slider_value()

    def callback_exit(self):
            if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really wish to quit?"):
                self.root.destroy()
                self.root.quit()
                rospy.signal_shutdown("shutdown")

    def slider_value(self):

                self.root = Tk()
                self.root.title("fine tune")
                self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback_exit)
                self.y_var = DoubleVar()

                self.y_scale = Scale( self.root, from_=self.eulerval[0]-1, to=self.eulerval[0]+1, length=300, label="yaw", resolution=0.0000000000001, variable = self.y_var, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.pub_y)
                self.y_scale.set(self.eulerval[0])
                self.y_scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)

                self.label = Label(self.root)
                self.label.pack()    
                self.root.mainloop()

    def pub_y(self, val_y):

            self.eulerval[0] = float(self.y_scale.get())
            self.final_ev.Euler_angles = [self.eulerval[0], self.eulerval[1], self.eulerval[2]]
            self.spub.publish(self.final_ev)
            rospy.loginfo(self.final_ev)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
           slider()

    except:
           rospy.loginfo("Node terminated.")
```

I would be grateful if you could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that rospy is internally multithreaded yet Tk is *very* keen on only being used from a single thread. (Technically, it's possible to use Tk from multiple threads — by appropriate quarantining of window objects and so on — but it's **really tricky** to get right and you probably don't want that.)

The easiest approach in general is to make two classes, one that *just* handles Tk (with incoming and outgoing messages *all* queued) and the other which does the bridging into the rest of the code. Then, when you want the Tk GUI to appear you run a thread that just does that and then talk to that thread just by its queues. Which sounds like a lot more work, but you can't defeat Tk's internal awareness of threads other than by keeping it strictly on one thread.

However, it *might* be enough to change the shutdown sequence a bit to be like this.

```
    def callback_exit(self):
        if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really wish to quit?"):
            self.root.destroy()
            rospy.signal_shutdown("shutdown")
            sys.exit(0)
```

Assuming that you're in the correct thread. If not, you'll need a direct `os._exit(0)` instead and that's considered dangerous for good reason (yet it might be necessary).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `sys.exit(0)` did not work. As far as I know, `os._exit(0)` would terminate your program immediately. What are the risks involved? Also, I'm not familiar with Multithreading and Queues. Can you provide an example code? Thanks!